# extra space in reading file ..?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

this is code i m using for reading from file and print to console ..but the code is taking an extra whitespace in front of text

```
         try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("D:\\actual.txt") );
        String a = " ";
        int c;
        while ((c= br.read())!=-1) {
            a = a + Character.toString((char)c);
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    br.close();
```

as my content is

```
               "hello world"
```

but on console it's taking an space befor text as

```
               " hello world"
```

Comment: Isn't it simple? You are initializing `a` as `" "` ie. a space

Comment: Replace  this `String a = " ";` with `String a = "";`

Answer (score 4):

You have declared `a` as `String a = " ";`. change it to `String a = "";` to remove the white space.

`a = a + Character.toString((char)c);` will concatenate `c` with the current contents of `a` and since a already has a space, that space is being concatenated with the text.

Comment: oh man..what a stupidity...thanxx bro..i have to wait 11 min to accept ur ans..:)

Answer (score 1):

You are buiding your output string concatenating it with the read character. That's ok but your initial String is " " instead "".

By the way, If your file is relatively big I would recoment you to use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).